# XCTest, a ViewController with a Nib & MKMapView

Tags: ios7, mkmapview, nib, xctest

I am trying to test that my map is showing location parameters that I give it. I am using a Nib for my view controller (I hate Storyboards).

The problem I've run into is that my map is nil in my test. The map is initialized in the Nib and isn't being initialized in my current code. I tried initializing my Nib with my ViewController, but that doesn't appear to work in XCTest.

```
#import <XCTest/XCTest.h>
#include "HomeVC.h"

@interface homeVCTests : XCTestCase {
    HomeVC* homeVC;
}

@end

@implementation homeVCTests

- (void)setUp
{
    [super setUp];

    homeVC = [[HomeVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeVC" bundle:nil];
    [homeVC viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)tearDown
{
    [super tearDown];
}

- (void)testHomeHasMap // Fails
{
    XCTAssertNotNil(homeVC.map, @"Map is not nil.");
}

- (void)testHomeHasMapTypeHybrid // Fails
{
    XCTAssertEqual(homeVC.map.mapType, MKMapTypeHybrid, @"Map type is hybrid(2)");
}

- (void)testHomeHasMapWithMyLocation // Fails
{
    [homeVC setMapCurrentLocation:37.785834 lon:-122.406417];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D checkpoint = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.785834, -122.406417);
    XCTAssertEqual(homeVC.map.centerCoordinate.latitude, checkpoint.latitude, @"Map shows my location.");
}

@end
```

HomeVC.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@class User;
@class LoginRegisterVC;

@interface HomeVC : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate> {
IBOutlet MKMapView* map;
CLLocationManager* locationManager;
CLLocationCoordinate2D currentLocation;
LoginRegisterVC* loginRegVC;

User* user;

}
@property(nonatomic, strong)LoginRegisterVC* loginRegVC;
@property(nonatomic, strong)User* user;
@property(nonatomic, strong)IBOutlet MKMapView* map;
@property(nonatomic, strong)CLLocationManager* locationManager;
@property(nonatomic)CLLocationCoordinate2D currentLocation;


-(void)setMapCurrentLocation:(float)lat lon:(float)lon;
@end
```

HomeVC.m

```
#import "HomeVC.h"
#import "User.h"
#import "LoginRegisterVC.h"

#define METERS_PER_MILE 1609.344

@interface HomeVC ()

@end

@implementation HomeVC
@synthesize map, locationManager, loginRegVC, user;
@synthesize currentLocation = _currentLocation;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
// Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

//self.map = MKMapView.new;
self.map.mapType = MKMapTypeHybrid;
self.map.delegate = self;

//NSLog(@"%lu", self.map.mapType);

[self startStandardUpdates];

[self setMapCurrentLocation:self.locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude
lon:self.locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewDidAppear:true];

if (self.user.loggedIn==false) {
self.loginRegVC = LoginRegisterVC.new;
self.loginRegVC.user = self.user;
[self presentViewController:self.loginRegVC animated:true completion:nil];
}
}

- (void)startStandardUpdates
{
if (nil == self.locationManager)
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

self.locationManager.delegate = self;
self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 5; // meters

[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
NSLog(@"%f, %f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude, newLocation.coordinate.longitude);
[self setMapCurrentLocation:newLocation.coordinate.latitude lon:newLocation.coordinate.longitude];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager monitoringDidFailForRegion:(CLRegion *)region withError:(NSError *)error
{

}

-(void)setMapCurrentLocation:(float)lat lon:(float)lon
{
self.currentLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lon);
MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(self.currentLocation,
0.5*METERS_PER_MILE,
0.5*METERS_PER_MILE);
[self.map setRegion:region animated:true];
NSLog(@"map center: %f, %f", self.map.centerCoordinate.latitude, self.map.centerCoordinate.longitude);
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to make unit tests like this for view controllers which implement asynchronous methods. Your test methods are executing instantly so you cannot see the results. You could use semaphores or other techniques to pause runloop until the states fulfil your requirements.